# PDF font display issue

Tags: pdf, fonts

I have a PDF font issue here,

I was using PDF factory pro to print out quotation from an accounting software application, but I have no idea why the font become as shown, should not have those space between the characters, I have check the data and back end code they are correct, so I was suspect is PDF setting or window font issue:
[image]

I have tried to update the font version by downloading the package online, but the issue remained.

Please help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you should set->fonts(); 
if you cann't set font this pdf library then you can use tcppdf from tcppdf.org . 
I think you can solve your problem. 
thanks

Comment: can you explain more about set -> fonts()

Comment: set->fonts(); use in TCP PDF library . I don't use pdf factory . but I know you need to set fonts.so you can switch to TCP PDF.